# Bootjack Modal generates exception: Class 'TransitionEvent' has no instance getter 'relatedTarget'

Tags: modal-dialog, dart, rikulo, bootjack

I use Rikulo/Bootjack to input parameters in the modal window but dquery generates multiple exceptions "Class 'TransitionEvent' has no instance getter 'relatedTarget'" in the DartEditor-1.10.1 (Win7 and Linux) with the Preferences: Run and Debug: Break on exceptions: all. What is the problem? Here is sample code:

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>bootjack_test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="packages/bootjack/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script async src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#modalNewItem" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">New item</a>
  <div id="modalNewItem" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4>New item creation:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          Item name:&nbsp;<input type="text" id="inputItemName">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnCreateItem">Create</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.dart:**

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:dquery/dquery.dart';
import 'package:bootjack/bootjack.dart';

void main() {
  Modal.use();
  Transition.use();
  Modal modal = Modal.wire(querySelector('#modalNewItem'));

  $('#btnCreateItem').on('click', (QueryEvent e) {
    var itemName = (querySelector('#inputItemName') as TextInputElement).value.trim();
    if (itemName.length == 0) {
      print('ERROR: empty item name');
    } else {
      print('OK: item name = $itemName');
      modal.hide();
    }
  });
}
```

The problem reproduces in bootjack example/modal from rikulo/bootjack
GitHub, I opened corresponding issue request: https://github.com/rikulo/bootjack/issues/25

Comment: I suggest you create a bug report in the bootjack GitHub repo. Please crosslink the issue with this question if you create an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed dquery, please run `pub upgrade` to upgrade dquery to 0.7.1+1.